# limit the number of groups shown in seaborn countplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Is it possible to show only the top/bottom *n* groups in a`sns.countplot()`?

Using an example from the seaborn website,

```
sns.countplot(y="deck", hue="class", data=titanic, palette="Greens_d");
```

[image]

Is there any easy (or even relatively straightforward) way of limiting this plot to just 3 decks (groups) instead of displaying all 7 or is this something that would be better accomplished with an `sns.bargraph` or just plain matplotlib?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
sns.countplot(y="deck", hue="class", data=titanic, palette="Greens_d",
              order=titanic.deck.value_counts().iloc[:3].index)
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Just adding real example instead of toy dataset.
Assuming you have Pandas Data Frame name training_var and you want to display top 10 'Gene' column counts 'order=' bit should look as follows:

```
sb.countplot(x='Gene',data=training_var,order=pd.value_counts(training_var['Gene']).iloc[:10].index)
```