# Facing Problem in counting multi-label for classification

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to count the number of labels for my multilabel classification, but I fail to plot a bar graph for my label column. Is there anybody who can help me out? i already used below code to plot but it shows

> *'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'arange'

As you can see the multiple labels are there in a Label column so I want to plot a bar graph for them please help me out
[image: screenshot]

```
 i=data.arange(20)
tag_df_sorted.head(20).plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('Frequency of top 20 tags')
plt.xticks(i, tag_df_sorted['Labels'])
plt.xlabel('Tags')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you want `import numpy as np` and `np.arange(20)`?

Comment: To create a count plot, `import seaborn as sns` and then `sns.countplot(data=tag_df, x='Labels')` might work. See [limit the number of groups shown in seaborn countplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891211/limit-the-number-of-groups-shown-in-seaborn-countplot) for a way to show only the top-20.

Comment: Or `tag_df['Labels'].count_values()[:20].plot.bar(rot=90)` followed by `plt.tight_layout()` to fit the label texts into the figure.

Comment: already imported these two libraries but still, I am getting the same error

Comment: Did you replace `data.arange`  with `np.arange`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to have a histogram.
You can either go like this:

```py
tag_df_sorted.groupby('Labels').count().plot()
```

or with Pandas's [`hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) function:

```py
# number of unique values in the column "Labels"
Num = len(tag_df_sorted['Labels'].unique())
# plot histogram
hist = tag_df_sorted['Labels'].hist(bins=Num )
```

There is a nice little tutorial on plotting histograms [here](https://data36.com/plot-histogram-python-pandas/).

Comment: not working I tried this